# Intercept URLs based on patterns with Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, adblock

Scenario:

- filter some redirect URLs based on patterns
- Show a message stating that a URL was blocked due to a redirect
- "unblock" a request in the same tab if a previous request was blocked

My list of URL patterns to use in webRequest.onBeforeRequest contains *bit.ly*. Then I hit the URL *bit.ly/2qlHCT* which redirects to google.com. In this case, I'll show a message like "request was blocked", but I don't want to actually block the request by returning { cancel: true } in onBeforeRequest's callback.

If the user tries to normally access google.com in the same tab, then I'll show a message "nothing was blocked".
So, this is similar what Adblock does when you add filters for a specific domain. Adblock's icon goes green if the domain is allowed, otherwise it turns red.

I know that I can use chrome.storage to save information about a blocked request, but how can I achieve that when a URL pattern doesn't match?

Comment: When it doesn't match the page is loaded normally so all you need is a listener for any event that occurs later like onHeadersReceived or webNavigation.onCompleted and so on.

Comment: I tried that, but I wrapped chrome.storage get and set methods into Promises to avoid chrome.runtime errors. So, I'm dealing with async functions inside a sync function (onBeforeRequest). Basically, what I want is to know if my listener  was called.

Comment: That doesn't matter for the idea I suggested. Anyway, without code this question is unlikely to be answered.

Comment: I still need to block the tab until the user starts a new navigation from a different domain. If _bit.ly/2qlHCT_ redirects to google.com, the tab should remain blocked if the user searches for something on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was really straightforward. I was using `chrome.tabs.query` to block tabs, but it's an async method and I needed a sync response. Using `localStorage` did the trick.

```
function blockRequest(tabId) {
  let tabs = localStorage.blocked_tabs;
  tabs = (tabs !== undefined) ? JSON.parse(tabs) : [];
  tabs = tabs.filter(function (item) {
    return item !== tabId;
  });
  localStorage.setItem('blocked_tabs', JSON.stringify(tabs));
}
```

Then, I just added the function blockRequest as listener to `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` and some filters.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(blockRequest, { urls: filters, types: ['main_frame'] });
```